# Wrong line color in pgfplot legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

How can I make sure the line through the brown square in the legend (to be clearer, at R^2) is green, just like the straight line of the graph?

[image]

That's my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
 grid,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!0},
  ymin=0,ymax=14,
  xmax=14,xmin=0,
  xtick={2,4,6,8,10,12},
  ytick={2,4,6,8,10,12},
  extra x ticks={0},
  extra y ticks={0},
            width=7cm,
            height=7cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  style={thick}
               ]              
        \addplot [green,smooth,thick,domain=0:12] {1.0016*x};
        \addlegendentry{$f(x) = 1.0016x$};
        \addplot[mark=square*,brown] coordinates {(0.1384,0.1338)};
        \addplot[mark=square*,brown] coordinates {(1.288,1.278)};
        \addplot[mark=square*,brown] coordinates {(11.65,11.67)};
        \addlegendentry{$R^2 = 1.000$};
    \end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to provide the legend entries and the corresponding images separately in advance, using a list of `legend entries` in the axis options and `\addlegendimage` commands at the start of your plot. This allows you to specify the line color and the marker color separately.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
 grid,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!0},
  ymin=0,ymax=14,
  xmax=14,xmin=0,
  xtick={2,4,6,8,10,12},
  ytick={2,4,6,8,10,12},
  extra x ticks={0},
  extra y ticks={0},
            width=7cm,
            height=7cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  style={thick},
  legend entries={$f(x) = 1.0016x$, $R^2 = 1.000$}
               ]
  \addlegendimage{no markers, green, thick}
  \addlegendimage{green, thick, mark=square*, mark options={solid,draw=brown,fill=brown}}
        \addplot [green,smooth,thick,domain=0:12] {1.0016*x};
        \addplot[mark=square*,brown] coordinates {(0.1384,0.1338)};
        \addplot[mark=square*,brown] coordinates {(1.288,1.278)};
        \addplot[mark=square*,brown] coordinates {(11.65,11.67)};
    \end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that it may be conceptually more correct to add the R² boxes in the legend without the line. This can be done using your original code but specifying `only marks` in your `\addplot` commands:

```
\addplot[only marks, mark=square*,brown] coordinates {(0.1384,0.1338)};
\addplot[only marks, mark=square*,brown] coordinates {(1.288,1.278)};
\addplot[only marks, mark=square*,brown] coordinates {(11.65,11.67)};
\addlegendentry{$R^2 = 1.000$};
```

[image]

This also allows you to provide all coordinates at once without drawing a line between them:

```
\addplot[only marks, mark=square*,brown] coordinates {(0.1384,0.1338) (1.288,1.278) (11.65,11.67)};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, expecially for the last hint!

Comment: @user3204810 you can also compress the three plots into one, see edit.