# Scatter plot: Legend and line color don't match

Tags: pgfplots, color, legend

I've defined the colors of the scatter plot based on the value of a data column. In addition to the values themselves, I'm plotting the mean, which has its separate column. However, the mean plot and legend don't match in color. The color of the first class (gree) is repeated, because it shares the same value (0). Even specifying `\addplot[color=black]` does not help, only the marks, but not the line change color.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{mgelb}{RGB}{255, 187, 0}
    \definecolor{mblau}{RGB}{10, 59, 104}
    \definecolor{mturkis}{RGB}{0, 171, 183}
    \definecolor{mrot}{RGB}{255, 70, 70}
    \definecolor{mrot2}{RGB}{184, 0, 0}
    \definecolor{mgrun}{RGB}{41, 175, 0}
    \definecolor{mlila}{RGB}{136, 55, 155}
    \definecolor{mgrau1}{RGB}{230, 230, 230}
    \definecolor{mgrau2}{RGB}{204, 204, 204}
    \definecolor{mgrau3}{RGB}{153, 153, 153}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{legend cell align={left}, legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.3cm}}}

\begin{document}

    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/read comma as period}

    \pgfplotstableread{
        Quadrant    Bereich Nummer  Rz_m    Rz_m_B  Rz_m_Q
        0       0   1   67,9    51,5 51,5
        0       0   2   44,17   nan nan
        0       0   3   44,3    nan nan
        0       0   4   63,43   nan nan
        0       0   5   49,87   nan nan
        0       0   6   39,33   nan nan
        I       i   1   44,33   50,55 54,24
        I       i   2   50,97   nan nan
        I       i   3   55,9    nan nan
        I       i   4   51,33   nan nan
        I       i   5   58,23   nan nan
        I       i   6   44,53   nan nan
        I       a   1   61,17   54,9 nan
        I       a   2   69,37   nan nan
        I       a   3   66,2    nan nan
        I       a   4   44,2    nan nan
        I       a   5   64,77   nan nan
        I       a   6   39,93   nan nan
        II  i   1   63,93   nan 53,21
        II  i   2   47,37   nan nan
        II  i   3   46,9    nan nan
        II  i   4   34,73   nan nan
        II  i   5   41,27   nan nan
        II  i   6   48,23   nan nan
        II  a   1   50,03   nan nan
        II  a   2   47,4    nan nan
        II  a   3   58,67   nan nan
        II  a   4   71,57   nan nan
        II  a   5   57,6    nan nan
        II  a   6   70,77   nan nan
        III i   1   37,5    nan 48,25
        III i   2   55,5    nan nan
        III i   3   41,2    nan nan
        III i   4   48,07   nan nan
        III i   5   56,8    nan nan
        III i   6   49,77   nan nan
        III a   1   58,3    nan nan
        III a   2   47,07   nan nan
        III a   3   50,53   nan nan
        III a   4   51,2    nan nan
        III a   5   32,67   nan nan
        III a   6   50,37   nan nan
        IV  i   1   51,6    nan 55,22
        IV  i   2   45,53   nan nan
        IV  i   3   60,27   nan nan
        IV  i   4   71      nan nan
        IV  i   5   59,63   nan nan
        IV  i   6   48,7    nan nan
        IV  a   1   40,87   nan nan
        IV  a   2   44,43   nan nan
        IV  a   3   44      nan nan
        IV  a   4   60,03   nan nan
        IV  a   5   63,73   nan nan
        IV  a   6   72,8    nan nan
    }\data


    \begin{figure}
        \centering\small
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={group size=2 by 1, ylabels at=edge left, horizontal sep=2cm},
                xtick=data,
                ymin=0,
                ylabel=Oberflächenrauheit $R_{z}$ in \si{\um},
                legend pos=south west,
                legend columns=-1,
                width=0.55\textwidth,
                height=0.6\textwidth,
                clip mode=individual
        ]
                \nextgroupplot[
                        symbolic x coords={0, i, a},
                        xlabel={Bereich},
                        scatter/classes={0={mgrun}, I={mblau, xshift=-1.4mm}, II={mgelb, xshift=1.5mm}, III={mturkis, xshift=-3mm}, IV={mrot2, xshift=3mm}}
                ]

                    \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[meta=Quadrant, scatter src=explicit symbolic, x=Bereich, y=Rz_m] {\data};

                    \addplot[black, mark=triangle, mark options={black, scale=2}, scatter] table[scatter src=explicit symbolic, x=Bereich, y=Rz_m_B] {\data};

                    \legend{0, I, II, III, IV, $\overline{R_{z}}$}

                \nextgroupplot[
                        symbolic x coords={0, I, II, III, IV},
                        xlabel={Quadrant},
                        scatter/classes={0={mlila}, i={mrot, xshift=-1mm}, a={mgrau3, xshift=1mm}},
                ]
                    \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[meta=Bereich, scatter src=explicit symbolic, x=Quadrant, y=Rz_m, y error=Rz_s] {\data};

                    \addplot[black,
                            mark=triangle,
                            mark options={scale=2},
                            scatter,
                            error bars/.cd,
                            y dir=both,
                            y explicit
                    ] table[scatter src=explicit symbolic, x=Quadrant, y=Rz_m_Q] {\data};

                    \legend{0, i, a, $\overline{R_{z}}$}
        \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try using `\addlegendimage`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553002/wrong-line-color-in-pgfplot-legend/553009.

Comment: @Marijn I saw that option too, but considering that I have a lot of plots to make and maybe alter, this seems like a lot of work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your R<sub>z</sub> plots are defined as `scatter`, and therefore they take the properties of the scatter classes, including the color. If you define them as regular plots with `point meta` coordinates then the legend will use the properties of the individual plot commands.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{mgelb}{RGB}{255, 187, 0}
    \definecolor{mblau}{RGB}{10, 59, 104}
    \definecolor{mturkis}{RGB}{0, 171, 183}
    \definecolor{mrot}{RGB}{255, 70, 70}
    \definecolor{mrot2}{RGB}{184, 0, 0}
    \definecolor{mgrun}{RGB}{41, 175, 0}
    \definecolor{mlila}{RGB}{136, 55, 155}
    \definecolor{mgrau1}{RGB}{230, 230, 230}
    \definecolor{mgrau2}{RGB}{204, 204, 204}
    \definecolor{mgrau3}{RGB}{153, 153, 153}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{legend cell align={left}, legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.3cm}}}

\begin{document}

    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/read comma as period}

    \pgfplotstableread{
        Quadrant    Bereich Nummer  Rz_m    Rz_m_B  Rz_m_Q
        0       0   1   67,9    51,5 51,5
        0       0   2   44,17   nan nan
        0       0   3   44,3    nan nan
        0       0   4   63,43   nan nan
        0       0   5   49,87   nan nan
        0       0   6   39,33   nan nan
        I       i   1   44,33   50,55 54,24
        I       i   2   50,97   nan nan
        I       i   3   55,9    nan nan
        I       i   4   51,33   nan nan
        I       i   5   58,23   nan nan
        I       i   6   44,53   nan nan
        I       a   1   61,17   54,9 nan
        I       a   2   69,37   nan nan
        I       a   3   66,2    nan nan
        I       a   4   44,2    nan nan
        I       a   5   64,77   nan nan
        I       a   6   39,93   nan nan
        II  i   1   63,93   nan 53,21
        II  i   2   47,37   nan nan
        II  i   3   46,9    nan nan
        II  i   4   34,73   nan nan
        II  i   5   41,27   nan nan
        II  i   6   48,23   nan nan
        II  a   1   50,03   nan nan
        II  a   2   47,4    nan nan
        II  a   3   58,67   nan nan
        II  a   4   71,57   nan nan
        II  a   5   57,6    nan nan
        II  a   6   70,77   nan nan
        III i   1   37,5    nan 48,25
        III i   2   55,5    nan nan
        III i   3   41,2    nan nan
        III i   4   48,07   nan nan
        III i   5   56,8    nan nan
        III i   6   49,77   nan nan
        III a   1   58,3    nan nan
        III a   2   47,07   nan nan
        III a   3   50,53   nan nan
        III a   4   51,2    nan nan
        III a   5   32,67   nan nan
        III a   6   50,37   nan nan
        IV  i   1   51,6    nan 55,22
        IV  i   2   45,53   nan nan
        IV  i   3   60,27   nan nan
        IV  i   4   71      nan nan
        IV  i   5   59,63   nan nan
        IV  i   6   48,7    nan nan
        IV  a   1   40,87   nan nan
        IV  a   2   44,43   nan nan
        IV  a   3   44      nan nan
        IV  a   4   60,03   nan nan
        IV  a   5   63,73   nan nan
        IV  a   6   72,8    nan nan
    }\data


    \begin{figure}
        \centering\small
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={group size=2 by 1, ylabels at=edge left, horizontal sep=2cm},
                xtick=data,
                ymin=0,
                ylabel=Oberflächenrauheit $R_{z}$ in \si{\um},
                legend pos=south west,
                legend columns=-1,
                width=0.55\textwidth,
                height=0.6\textwidth,
                clip mode=individual
        ]
                \nextgroupplot[
                        symbolic x coords={0, i, a},
                        xlabel={Bereich},
                        scatter/classes={0={mgrun}, I={mblau, xshift=-1.4mm}, II={mgelb, xshift=1.5mm}, III={mturkis, xshift=-3mm}, IV={mrot2, xshift=3mm}}
                ]

                    \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[meta=Quadrant, scatter src=explicit symbolic, x=Bereich, y=Rz_m] {\data};

                    \addplot[black, mark=triangle, mark options={scale=2}] table[point meta=explicit symbolic, x=Bereich, y=Rz_m_B] {\data};

                    \legend{0, I, II, III, IV, $\overline{R_{z}}$}

                \nextgroupplot[
                        symbolic x coords={0, I, II, III, IV},
                        xlabel={Quadrant},
                        scatter/classes={0={mlila}, i={mrot, xshift=-1mm}, a={mgrau3, xshift=1mm}},
                ]
                    \addplot[scatter, only marks] table[meta=Bereich, scatter src=explicit symbolic, x=Quadrant, y=Rz_m, y error=Rz_s] {\data};

                    \addplot[black,
                            mark=triangle,
                            mark options={scale=2},
                    ] table[point meta=explicit symbolic, x=Quadrant, y=Rz_m_Q] {\data};

                    \legend{0, i, a, $\overline{R_{z}}$}
        \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what the difference is?